# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'cmcwebapp'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router

I am using angular 4. My angular app works fine when I run it with "ng serve". That's when it run with context-root as "/".

My app need to compile with java webapp and is Deployed to servlet-container as part of war file. this app runs under context-root 'cmcwebapp'.

my index.html has element

```
<base href="/">
```

just under "head" element. and When I compile angular app I use command

```
 ng build --base-href cmcwebapp
```

Once this compiles I copy contents of dist folder and paste it into java webapp and creates a war file.

when I run this on browser with "http://localhost:8080/cmcwebapp". all the javascript, css and images loads fine. the URL changes to "http://localhost:8080/cmcwebapp/cmcwebapp/" and I get this "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'cmcwebapp'".

I have this as my routes definition in app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'distribute', component: DistributeComponent },
  { path: 'consume', component: ConsumeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DistributeComponent,
    ConsumeComponent 
 ],
  imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   HttpModule,
   RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
   WjGridModule
 ],
 providers: [EppmService],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent] 
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and this is my app.component.html

```
<div class="menu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="overflow:hidden">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="home">home</a></li>
               <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="distribute">Distribute</a></li>
               <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="consume">Consume</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="submission">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong

Comment: I think you have to try without base href

Comment: I did try that but javascript, CSS and images doesn't load then and neither does that page works.

Comment: remove `/` from index.html in href

Comment: did it worked,did you try it?

Comment: yes that didnot work however it worked when I compiled with "ng build --base-href ." . Now I have another issue is that when I type say "http://localhost:8080/cmcwebapp/home" it throw 404 error. It works when I type "http://localhost:8080/cmcwebapp"

Comment: `"localhost:8080/home"` try this

Comment: that will not work as application is running at /cmcwebapp